# how to create an antlr4 identifier token that accepts any unicode word?

Tags: parsing, unicode, antlr4

Antlr4 supports unicode.

I have tried creating a rule with unicode characters, and it works, something like:

```
IDENT:
    [A-Za-zα-ω][A-Za-zα-ω0-9]* ;
```

but of course putting in all the letters from all potential alphabets is wildly complicated.
So my question is, has this been done somewhere? I couldn't find it. Is there any reasonably compact way of writing this, or is it wildly complicated, hundreds of lines long, with ranges for each language?

Answer (score 1):

I think most targets in ANTLR support Unicode Categories. So you should be able to match any letter using `\p{L}`:

```
IDENT
 : [\p{L}] [\p{L}0-9]*
 ;
```